# add Load Modulesbutton to text editor

Tags: joomla-3.x, editor

i have created a portfolio component that use text editor , and i want add the Load Modules button unther the text editor , normaly it load the button automatickly on joomla articles ..

also is there any way to add it ?

thanks
amine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using the Form API, add `buttons="true"` attribute to your editor field. Example from article form:

```
<field
    name="articletext"
    type="editor"
    label="COM_CONTENT_FIELD_ARTICLETEXT_LABEL"
    description="COM_CONTENT_FIELD_ARTICLETEXT_DESC"
    filter="JComponentHelper::filterText"
    buttons="true"
/>
```

Comment: YES . THIS WAS THE FIX